# Select records if they contain all of the subquery results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a select statement. I want to select records which contains all the records from subquery.

I have a subquery like:

```
SELECT P.pid
FROM Parts P
INNER JOIN Manifacturers M INNER JOIN M.mid ON P.pid
WHERE M.name = 'Mercedes'
```

I want to select suppliers if they sell all of these parts. I tried couple of things:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM Suppliers S
INNER JOIN Parts P1 ON S.pid = P1.pid
WHERE p1.pid IN ( SELECT P.pid
    FROM Parts P
    INNER JOIN Manifacturers M INNER JOIN M.mid ON P.pid
    WHERE M.name = 'Mercedes' )
```

This clearly failed. This returns suppliers if they have any of the parts. Actually I manage to get close by using INTERSECT:

```
SELECT P1.pid
FROM Suppliers S
INNER JOIN Parts P1 ON S.pid = P1.pid
INTERSECT
SELECT P.pid
FROM Parts P
INNER JOIN Manifacturers M INNER JOIN M.mid ON P.pid
WHERE M.name = 'Mercedes'
```

This returns the correct pids but this syntax doesn't allow me to return s.name. It won't let me add any field which doesn't exists in the second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using conditional `COUNT()`

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN M.name = 'Mercedes' THEN 1 END) AS total_mercedes
FROM Parts P
INNER JOIN Manifacturers M INNER JOIN M.mid ON P.pid
```

Then your manufactures must have the same number of parts.

```
SELECT s.name, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN M.name = 'Mercedes' THEN 1 END) AS total_supplier
FROM Suppliers S
INNER JOIN Parts P1 ON S.pid = P1.pid
INNER JOIN Manifacturers M INNER JOIN M.mid ON P.pid
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN M.name = 'Mercedes' THEN 1 END) AS total_mercedes
             FROM Parts P
             INNER JOIN Manifacturers M INNER JOIN M.mid ON P.pid
           ) M
GROUP BY s.name   
HAVING T.total_mercedes  = total_supplier
```

Another Option is with `LEFT JOIN`.

First you need every Pid from Mercedes and every supplier. Then check if have any `NULL` rows

```
SELECT S.name
FROM  ( SELECT P.Pid
        FROM Parts P
        INNER JOIN Manifacturers M INNER JOIN M.mid ON P.pid
        WHERE M.name = 'Mercedes'
      ) M
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT S.name, 
            FROM Suppliers S
           ) S
LEFT JOIN Suppliers Sales
      ON M.Pid = Sales.Pid
     AND S.name = Sales.Name
GROUP BY S.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Sales.Pid IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: @Matt Fix the `CASE`. But dont see how you can simplify the derived table, you need have a base with all part and supplier before do the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Ohh I see it... at first I use a join with Manufacturer, but the realize Supplier already have `Pid`.

Comment: Yep, it's no biggie either way I just thought it was cleaner without it.  good answer